# How to make a search with variables in textboxes & url variables?

Tags: php, html, ajax, .htaccess, url

I would like the following features:

- variable stays in textbox after search button clicked
- variables in the url
- When i change the url (edit the url) & refresh, variables put into textbox and new search is made

There is many pages to my search. All of them use ajax except the first page. So how can I also put what page the search result is on in the url?

```html
<form name="search1" action="/search.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search">
             <div class="box">
                    <span>What:</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="job title, keywords or company" value="{keyword}" name="keyword" />

                    <em>job title, keywords or company</em>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <span>Where:</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="city or postcode" value="" name="location" />
                    <em>city</em>
                </div>

                <div class="box box_submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="FIND" class="max" name="" />
                 <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="min" name="" />
                </div>

            </form>
```

**The url of the search only shows /search.php and I want the variables to be in there too.**

Answer (score 1):

Change Your Form `Method` to `Get` :

```
<form name="search1" action="/search.php" method="Get">
```

Like this the variables will be shown in the url
I hope this will help you

Comment: I tried this and it makes no difference to the url

Comment: Use one `Submit` button, this will fix it

Comment: I tried and it doesn't change anything

Comment: This code works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/rsm23/8fmem0xf/

Comment: https://youtu.be/h2Nq0qv0K8M?t=1h18m7s